# My Macbook Pro won't let me open the mail application. How do I fix this?

Tags: macbook-pro, applications, email, gmail

Every time I try to open my mailbox it comes up with the option only for me to quit or quit and rebuild mailboxes. Ive tried both options and neither will change anything.

Comment: Are you looking for a clean start - (i.e. all mail is on servers) or how to troubleshoot and find an actionable error?

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking but i just want to be able to open my mailbox app and access my emails without having to go to gmail.com so i need to figure out what to fix on my computer in order to do so